# Run Android Emulator - Segmentation Fault

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-virtual-device, android-sdk-tools

I want to run android emulator on CentOS linux without GUI in headless mode. When running it, segmentation fault error occured. It seems that emulator is runnig only once after reboot system, after that I can't run it. It fails when emulator starts proxying data.

I'm expecting run android emulator in headless mode and execute automated tests on that one.

Instruction used to create emulator:

```
./avdmanager create avd -n pixel_xl -k "system-images;android-28;google_apis;x86_64" -d "pixel_xl"
```

Instructions used to run emulator:

```
./emulator-headless -avd pixel_xl -verbose -wipe-data -no-snapshot-save -gpu off 

./emulator -avd pixel_xl -verbose -wipe-data -no-snapshot-save -no-audio -no-window
```

Logs:

```
emulator: Android emulator version 29.0.11.0 (build_id 5598178) (CL:N/A)
emulator: Found AVD name 'pixel_xl'
emulator: Found AVD target architecture: x86_64
emulator: Deleting file /root/.android/avd/pixel_xl.avd/system.img.qcow2 failed
emulator: Deleting file /root/.android/avd/pixel_xl.avd/vendor.img.qcow2 failed
emulator: Deleting file /root/.android/avd/pixel_xl.avd/userdata-qemu.img done
emulator: Deleting file /root/.android/avd/pixel_xl.avd/userdata-qemu.img.qcow2 failed
emulator: Deleting file /root/.android/avd/pixel_xl.avd/userdata.img failed
emulator: Deleting file /root/.android/avd/pixel_xl.avd/userdata.img.qcow2 failed
emulator: Deleting file /root/.android/avd/pixel_xl.avd/cache.img done
emulator: Deleting file /root/.android/avd/pixel_xl.avd/cache.img.qcow2 failed
emulator: Deleting file /root/.android/avd/pixel_xl.avd/version_num.cache failed
emulator: Deleting file /root/.android/avd/pixel_xl.avd/sdcard.img.qcow2 failed
emulator: Deleting file /root/.android/avd/pixel_xl.avd/encryptionkey.img done
emulator: Deleting file /root/.android/avd/pixel_xl.avd/encryptionkey.img.qcow2 failed
emulator: Deleting file /root/.android/avd/pixel_xl.avd/hardware-qemu.ini failed
emulator: Deleting file /root/.android/avd/pixel_xl.avd/emulator-user.ini failed
emulator: Deleting file /root/.android/avd/pixel_xl.avd/default.dtb failed
emulator: Failed to remove snapshot directory '/root/.android/avd/pixel_xl.avd/snapshots'
emulator: Removed ADB command directory '/root/.android/avd/pixel_xl.avd/tmpAdbCmds'
emulator: argv[0]: './emulator-headless'; program directory: '/opt/software/sdks/android/sdk/emulator'
emulator:  Found directory: /opt/software/sdks/android/sdk/system-images/android-28/google_apis/x86_64/

emulator: emuDirName: '/opt/software/sdks/android/sdk/emulator'
emulator: try dir /opt/software/sdks/android/sdk/emulator
emulator: Trying emulator path '/opt/software/sdks/android/sdk/emulator/qemu/linux-x86_64/qemu-system-x86_64-headless'
emulator: Found target-specific 64-bit emulator binary: /opt/software/sdks/android/sdk/emulator/qemu/linux-x86_64/qemu-system-x86_64-headless
emulator: Adding library search path: '/opt/software/sdks/android/sdk/emulator/lib64'
emulator: Adding library search path: '/opt/software/sdks/android/sdk/emulator/lib64/gles_swiftshader'
emulator: Adding library search path: '/opt/software/sdks/android/sdk/emulator/lib64/gles_angle'
emulator: Adding library search path: '/opt/software/sdks/android/sdk/emulator/lib64/gles_angle9'
emulator: Adding library search path: '/opt/software/sdks/android/sdk/emulator/lib64/gles_angle11'
emulator: Adding library search path: '/opt/software/sdks/android/sdk/emulator/lib64/libstdc++'
emulator: Running :/opt/software/sdks/android/sdk/emulator/qemu/linux-x86_64/qemu-system-x86_64-headless
emulator: qemu backend: argv[00] = "/opt/software/sdks/android/sdk/emulator/qemu/linux-x86_64/qemu-system-x86_64-headless"
emulator: qemu backend: argv[01] = "-avd"
emulator: qemu backend: argv[02] = "pixel_xl"
emulator: qemu backend: argv[03] = "-verbose"
emulator: qemu backend: argv[04] = "-wipe-data"
emulator: qemu backend: argv[05] = "-no-snapshot-save"
emulator: qemu backend: argv[06] = "-gpu"
emulator: qemu backend: argv[07] = "off"
emulator: Concatenated backend parameters:
 /opt/software/sdks/android/sdk/emulator/qemu/linux-x86_64/qemu-system-x86_64-headless -avd pixel_xl -verbose -wipe-data -no-snapshot-save -gpu off
emulator: autoconfig: -skin 1440x2560
emulator: autoconfig: -skindir (null)
emulator: autoconfig: -kernel /opt/software/sdks/android/sdk/system-images/android-28/google_apis/x86_64//kernel-ranchu
emulator: Target arch = 'x86_64'
emulator: Auto-detect: Kernel image requires new device naming scheme.
emulator: Auto-detect: Kernel does not support YAFFS2 partitions.
emulator: autoconfig: -ramdisk /opt/software/sdks/android/sdk/system-images/android-28/google_apis/x86_64//ramdisk.img
emulator: Using initial system image: /opt/software/sdks/android/sdk/system-images/android-28/google_apis/x86_64//system.img
emulator: Using initial vendor image: /opt/software/sdks/android/sdk/system-images/android-28/google_apis/x86_64//vendor.img
emulator: autoconfig: -initdata /opt/software/sdks/android/sdk/system-images/android-28/google_apis/x86_64//userdata.img
emulator: autoconfig: -cache /root/.android/avd/pixel_xl.avd/cache.img
emulator: Increasing RAM size to 1536MB
emulator: VM heap size 0MB is below hardware specified minimum of 384MB,setting it to that value
emulator: System image is read only
emulator: Found 3 DNS servers: 192.44.120.10 137.183.226.11 143.26.128.29
emulator: found magic skin width=1440 height=2560 bpp=16

emulator: registered 'boot-properties' qemud service
emulator: Adding boot property: 'qemu.cmdline' = 'androidboot.logcat=v:* androidboot.consolepipe=qemu_pipe,pipe:logcat'
emulator: Adding boot property: 'qemu.logcat' = 'start'
emulator: Creating ext4 userdata partition: /root/.android/avd/pixel_xl.avd/data
Creating filesystem with parameters:
    Size: 838860800
    Block size: 4096
    Blocks per group: 32768
    Inodes per group: 7328
    Inode size: 256
    Journal blocks: 3200
    Label:
    Blocks: 204800
    Block groups: 7
    Reserved block group size: 55
Created filesystem with 61/51296 inodes and 10842/204800 blocks
emulator: Creating empty ext4 cache partition: /root/.android/avd/pixel_xl.avd/cache.img
Creating filesystem with parameters:
    Size: 69206016
    Block size: 4096
    Blocks per group: 32768
    Inodes per group: 4224
    Inode size: 256
    Journal blocks: 1024
    Label:
    Blocks: 16896
    Block groups: 1
    Reserved block group size: 7
Created filesystem with 11/4224 inodes and 1302/16896 blocks
emulator: CPU Acceleration: working
emulator: CPU Acceleration status: KVM (version 12) is installed and usable.
emulator: VERBOSE: AdbInterface.cpp:232: Found: 3 adb executables
emulator: VERBOSE: AdbInterface.cpp:234: Adb: /opt/software/sdks/android/sdk/platform-tools/adb
emulator: VERBOSE: AdbInterface.cpp:234: Adb: /opt/software/sdks/android/sdk/platform-tools/adb
emulator: VERBOSE: AdbInterface.cpp:234: Adb: /opt/software/sdks/android/sdk/platform-tools/adb
emulator: VERBOSE: AdbInterface.cpp:253: Path:/opt/software/sdks/android/sdk/platform-tools/adb protocol version: 41
emulator: VERBOSE: AdbInterface.cpp:253: Path:/opt/software/sdks/android/sdk/platform-tools/adb protocol version: 41
emulator: VERBOSE: AdbInterface.cpp:253: Path:/opt/software/sdks/android/sdk/platform-tools/adb protocol version: 41
emulator: WARNING: Your AVD has been configured with an in-guest renderer, but the system image does not support guest rendering.Falling back to 'swiftshader_indirect' mode.
emulator: GPU emulation enabled using 'swiftshader_indirect' mode
emulator: Initializing hardware OpenGLES emulation support
emulator: Found 3 DNS servers: ............................
Content of hardware configuration file:
  hw.cpu.arch = x86_64
  hw.cpu.ncore = 2
  hw.ramSize = 1536
  hw.screen = multi-touch
  hw.mainKeys = false
  hw.trackBall = false
  hw.keyboard = false
  hw.keyboard.lid = false
  hw.keyboard.charmap = qwerty2
  hw.dPad = false
  hw.rotaryInput = false
  hw.gsmModem = true
  hw.gps = true
  hw.battery = true
  hw.accelerometer = true
  hw.gyroscope = true
  hw.audioInput = true
  hw.audioOutput = true
  hw.sdCard = true
  disk.cachePartition = true
  disk.cachePartition.path = /root/.android/avd/pixel_xl.avd/cache.img
  disk.cachePartition.size = 66m
  test.quitAfterBootTimeOut = -1
  test.delayAdbTillBootComplete = 0
  test.monitorAdb = 0
  hw.lcd.width = 1440
  hw.lcd.height = 2560
  hw.lcd.depth = 16
  hw.lcd.density = 560
  hw.lcd.backlight = true
  hw.displayRegion.0.1.xOffset = -1
  hw.displayRegion.0.1.yOffset = -1
  hw.displayRegion.0.1.width = 0
  hw.displayRegion.0.1.height = 0
  hw.fold.adjust = false
  hw.gpu.enabled = true
  hw.gpu.mode = swiftshader_indirect
  hw.initialOrientation = portrait
  hw.camera.back = emulated
  hw.camera.front = none
  vm.heapSize = 384
  hw.sensors.light = true
  hw.sensors.pressure = true
  hw.sensors.humidity = true
  hw.sensors.proximity = true
  hw.sensors.magnetic_field = true
  hw.sensors.magnetic_field_uncalibrated = true
  hw.sensors.gyroscope_uncalibrated = true
  hw.sensors.orientation = true
  hw.sensors.temperature = true
  hw.useext4 = true
  hw.arc = false
  hw.arc.autologin = false
  kernel.path = /opt/software/sdks/android/sdk/system-images/android-28/google_apis/x86_64//kernel-ranchu
  kernel.newDeviceNaming = yes
  kernel.supportsYaffs2 = no
  disk.ramdisk.path = /opt/software/sdks/android/sdk/system-images/android-28/google_apis/x86_64//ramdisk.img
  disk.systemPartition.initPath = /opt/software/sdks/android/sdk/system-images/android-28/google_apis/x86_64//system.img
  disk.systemPartition.size = 2562m
  disk.vendorPartition.initPath = /opt/software/sdks/android/sdk/system-images/android-28/google_apis/x86_64//vendor.img
  disk.vendorPartition.size = 800m
  disk.dataPartition.path = /root/.android/avd/pixel_xl.avd/userdata-qemu.img
  disk.dataPartition.initPath = /opt/software/sdks/android/sdk/system-images/android-28/google_apis/x86_64//userdata.img
  disk.dataPartition.size = 800m
  disk.encryptionKeyPartition.path = /root/.android/avd/pixel_xl.avd/encryptionkey.img
  PlayStore.enabled = false
  avd.name = pixel_xl
  fastboot.forceColdBoot = false
.
QEMU options list:
emulator: argv[00] = "/opt/software/sdks/android/sdk/emulator/qemu/linux-x86_64/qemu-system-x86_64-headless"
emulator: argv[01] = "-dns-server"
emulator: argv[02] = "………………………………………"
emulator: argv[03] = "-serial"
emulator: argv[04] = "null"
emulator: argv[05] = "-device"
emulator: argv[06] = "goldfish_pstore,addr=0xff018000,size=0x10000,file=/root/.android/avd/pixel_xl.avd/data/misc/pstore/pstore.bin"
emulator: argv[07] = "-cpu"
emulator: argv[08] = "android64"
emulator: argv[09] = "-enable-kvm"
emulator: argv[10] = "-smp"
emulator: argv[11] = "cores=2"
emulator: argv[12] = "-m"
emulator: argv[13] = "1536"
emulator: argv[14] = "-lcd-density"
emulator: argv[15] = "560"
emulator: argv[16] = "-object"
emulator: argv[17] = "iothread,id=disk-iothread"
emulator: argv[18] = "-nodefaults"
emulator: argv[19] = "-kernel"
emulator: argv[20] = "/opt/software/sdks/android/sdk/system-images/android-28/google_apis/x86_64//kernel-ranchu"
emulator: argv[21] = "-initrd"
emulator: argv[22] = "/opt/software/sdks/android/sdk/system-images/android-28/google_apis/x86_64//ramdisk.img"
emulator: argv[23] = "-drive"
emulator: argv[24] = "if=none,index=0,id=system,file=/opt/software/sdks/android/sdk/system-images/android-28/google_apis/x86_64//system.img,read-only"
emulator: argv[25] = "-device"
emulator: argv[26] = "virtio-blk-pci,drive=system,iothread=disk-iothread,modern-pio-notify"
emulator: argv[27] = "-drive"
emulator: argv[28] = "if=none,index=1,id=cache,file=/root/.android/avd/pixel_xl.avd/cache.img.qcow2,overlap-check=none,cache=unsafe,l2-cache-size=1048576"
emulator: argv[29] = "-device"
emulator: argv[30] = "virtio-blk-pci,drive=cache,iothread=disk-iothread,modern-pio-notify"
emulator: argv[31] = "-drive"
emulator: argv[32] = "if=none,index=2,id=userdata,file=/root/.android/avd/pixel_xl.avd/userdata-qemu.img.qcow2,overlap-check=none,cache=unsafe,l2-cache-size=1048576"
emulator: argv[33] = "-device"
emulator: argv[34] = "virtio-blk-pci,drive=userdata,iothread=disk-iothread,modern-pio-notify"
emulator: argv[35] = "-drive"
emulator: argv[36] = "if=none,index=3,id=encrypt,file=/root/.android/avd/pixel_xl.avd/encryptionkey.img.qcow2,overlap-check=none,cache=unsafe,l2-cache-size=1048576"
emulator: argv[37] = "-device"
emulator: argv[38] = "virtio-blk-pci,drive=encrypt,iothread=disk-iothread,modern-pio-notify"
emulator: argv[39] = "-drive"
emulator: argv[40] = "if=none,index=4,id=vendor,file=/opt/software/sdks/android/sdk/system-images/android-28/google_apis/x86_64//vendor.img,read-only"
emulator: argv[41] = "-device"
emulator: argv[42] = "virtio-blk-pci,drive=vendor,iothread=disk-iothread,modern-pio-notify"
emulator: argv[43] = "-netdev"
emulator: argv[44] = "user,id=mynet"
emulator: argv[45] = "-device"
emulator: argv[46] = "virtio-net-pci,netdev=mynet"
emulator: argv[47] = "-device"
emulator: argv[48] = "virtio-rng-pci"
emulator: argv[49] = "-show-cursor"
emulator: argv[50] = "-L"
emulator: argv[51] = "/opt/software/sdks/android/sdk/emulator/lib/pc-bios"
emulator: argv[52] = "-soundhw"
emulator: argv[53] = "hda"
emulator: argv[54] = "-vga"
emulator: argv[55] = "none"
emulator: argv[56] = "-append"
emulator: argv[57] = "qemu=1 no_timer_check androidboot.hardware=ranchu androidboot.serialno=EMULATOR29X0X11X0 clocksource=pit no-kvmclock android.qemud=1 console=0 android.checkjni=1 qemu.gles=1 qemu.settings.system.screen_off_timeout=2147483647 qemu.encrypt=1 qemu.opengles.version=131072 cma=314M@0-4G ndns=3 qemu.wifi=1 mac80211_hwsim.channels=2 androidboot.android_dt_dir=/sys/bus/platform/devices/ANDR0001:00/properties/android/ skip_initramfs rootwait ro init=/init loop.max_part=7 dm="1 vroot none ro 1,0 5159992 verity 1 PARTUUID=CDC502B1-71E4-4C31-AEC3-87250E21C0B8 PARTUUID=CDC502B1-71E4-4C31-AEC3-87250E21C0B8 4096 4096 644999 644999 sha1 4b9c37238cf8661b9099c4022d58a1aab10bec62 3f0e9a0fcc7cd635abd56d704b028ca2078049c6 1 ignore_zero_blocks" androidboot.veritymode=enforcing androidboot.verifiedbootstate=orange root=/dev/dm-0 ramoops.mem_address=0xff018000 ramoops.mem_size=0x10000 memmap=0x10000$0xff018000 qemu.dalvik.vm.heapsize=384m"
emulator: argv[58] = "-android-hw"
emulator: argv[59] = "/root/.android/avd/pixel_xl.avd/hardware-qemu.ini"
Concatenated QEMU options:
 /opt/software/sdks/android/sdk/emulator/qemu/linux-x86_64/qemu-system-x86_64-headless -dns-server ……………… -serial null -device goldfish_pstore,addr=0xff018000,size=0x10000,file=/root/.android/avd/pixel_xl.avd/data/misc/pstore/pstore.bin -cpu android64 -enable-kvm -smp cores=2 -m 1536 -lcd-density 560 -object iothread,id=disk-iothread -nodefaults -kernel /opt/software/sdks/android/sdk/system-images/android-28/google_apis/x86_64//kernel-ranchu -initrd /opt/software/sdks/android/sdk/system-images/android-28/google_apis/x86_64//ramdisk.img -drive if=none,index=0,id=system,file=/opt/software/sdks/android/sdk/system-images/android-28/google_apis/x86_64//system.img,read-only -device virtio-blk-pci,drive=system,iothread=disk-iothread,modern-pio-notify -drive if=none,index=1,id=cache,file=/root/.android/avd/pixel_xl.avd/cache.img.qcow2,overlap-check=none,cache=unsafe,l2-cache-size=1048576 -device virtio-blk-pci,drive=cache,iothread=disk-iothread,modern-pio-notify -drive if=none,index=2,id=userdata,file=/root/.android/avd/pixel_xl.avd/userdata-qemu.img.qcow2,overlap-check=none,cache=unsafe,l2-cache-size=1048576 -device virtio-blk-pci,drive=userdata,iothread=disk-iothread,modern-pio-notify -drive if=none,index=3,id=encrypt,file=/root/.android/avd/pixel_xl.avd/encryptionkey.img.qcow2,overlap-check=none,cache=unsafe,l2-cache-size=1048576 -device virtio-blk-pci,drive=encrypt,iothread=disk-iothread,modern-pio-notify -drive if=none,index=4,id=vendor,file=/opt/software/sdks/android/sdk/system-images/android-28/google_apis/x86_64//vendor.img,read-only -device virtio-blk-pci,drive=vendor,iothread=disk-iothread,modern-pio-notify -netdev user,id=mynet -device virtio-net-pci,netdev=mynet -device virtio-rng-pci -show-cursor -L /opt/software/sdks/android/sdk/emulator/lib/pc-bios -soundhw hda -vga none -append 'qemu=1 no_timer_check androidboot.hardware=ranchu androidboot.serialno=EMULATOR29X0X11X0 clocksource=pit no-kvmclock android.qemud=1 console=0 android.checkjni=1 qemu.gles=1 qemu.settings.system.screen_off_timeout=2147483647 qemu.encrypt=1 qemu.opengles.version=131072 cma=314M@0-4G ndns=3 qemu.wifi=1 mac80211_hwsim.channels=2 androidboot.android_dt_dir=/sys/bus/platform/devices/ANDR0001:00/properties/android/ skip_initramfs rootwait ro init=/init loop.max_part=7 dm="1 vroot none ro 1,0 5159992 verity 1 PARTUUID=CDC502B1-71E4-4C31-AEC3-87250E21C0B8 PARTUUID=CDC502B1-71E4-4C31-AEC3-87250E21C0B8 4096 4096 644999 644999 sha1 4b9c37238cf8661b9099c4022d58a1aab10bec62 3f0e9a0fcc7cd635abd56d704b028ca2078049c6 1 ignore_zero_blocks" androidboot.veritymode=enforcing androidboot.verifiedbootstate=orange root=/dev/dm-0 ramoops.mem_address=0xff018000 ramoops.mem_size=0x10000 memmap=0x10000$0xff018000 qemu.dalvik.vm.heapsize=384m' -android-hw /root/.android/avd/pixel_xl.avd/hardware-qemu.ini
emulator: Android qemu version 29.0.11.0 (build_id 5598178) (CL:N/A)

emulator: Starting QEMU main loop
emulator: Adding boot property: 'ro.opengles.version' = '131072'
emulator: Adding boot property: 'qemu.sf.fake_camera' = 'back'
emulator: Adding boot property: 'dalvik.vm.heapsize' = '384m'
emulator: Adding boot property: 'qemu.hw.mainkeys' = '0'
emulator: Adding boot property: 'qemu.sf.lcd_density' = '560'
emulator: goldfish_events.have-dpad: false
emulator: goldfish_events.have-trackball: false
emulator: goldfish_events.have-camera: true
emulator: goldfish_events.have-keyboard: false
emulator: goldfish_events.have-lidswitch: false
emulator: goldfish_events.have-tabletmode: false
emulator: goldfish_events.have-touch: false
emulator: goldfish_events.have-multitouch: true
emulator: control console listening on port 5554, ADB on port 5555
pulseaudio: Failed to initialize PA contextaudio: Could not init `pa' audio driver
setting up http proxy: proxy=104.129.198.34 port=9400
emulator: Adding boot property: 'qemu.timezone' = 'Etc/UCT'
emulator: android_hw_fingerprint_init: fingerprint qemud listen service initialized

emulator: emulator_window_fb_rotate

emulator: No acpi ini file provided, using defaul`enter code here`t

emulator: No acpi ini file provided, using default

emulator: onGuestSendCommand: [0x94d1e00] Adb connected, start proxing data
Segmentation fault
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to disable selinux.

Open file `/etc/selinux/config` and set `SELINUX=disabled`.

After reboot, ensure that command `sestatus` returns

> SELinux status: disabled

Comment: Disabling one of Linux's primary security mechanisms probably isn't the right solution.

Answer (score 0):

What helped me on my Arch Linux system (I have `gperftools` installed) was to copy the libtcmalloc_minimal.so.4 file to the SDK directory:

```
cp /usr/lib/libtcmalloc_minimal.so.4 emulator/lib64/libtcmalloc_minimal.so.4
```